# Aborting "git push" - open git-daemon-export-ok.19906 failed: Permission denied at pathto/gitolite.pm line 115

Tags: git, gitolite, git-daemon

I am using gitolite and now I am not able to push some changes / new files to the repository. I made no changes on permission's and I worked not on the git scripts. Do you hav an idea which reason this could be?

```
git push

Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 422 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: creating testrepo123...
remote: Initialized empty Git repository in /path/to/testrepo123.git/
remote:
remote:                 ***** ABORTING *****
remote:         open git-daemon-export-ok.19906 failed: Permission denied at /path/to/gitolite.pm line 115
To hasselbl@git.devlab.de.tmo:gitolite-admin.git
   dde5c24..ea1f2f9  master -> master
```

It is also not possible to create new repository. Git will create the repository on serverside but users are not able to work with them (permission)

I made no changes on permission side.
I hope you have an idea, all my web researches end without a result.

Kind regards,
Nils

Comment: `gitolite.pm`—there is no such file in the latest Gitolite sources. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`gitolite.pm` was [introduced in Oct. 2009](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/78d02e143760a0df8022dae601d809a4d452cab3) for Gitolite V2, whose last commit/tag is v2.3.1... seven years ago (May 2012)

Its `src/` subfolder did include a `gitolite.pm` file.
Only [commit ceb1154](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/ceb11543b1995b5057290b762939ce22f5436fd5) (Gitolite v2.3, plus 4 commits) shows a [`gitolite.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/ceb11543b1995b5057290b762939ce22f5436fd5/src/gitolite.pm#L115) with a command at line 115 susceptible to trigger that error message. (introduced with [commit 936f871](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/936f8719cef022c4188b002ab51518949be22f3d))

```
my $fh = wrap_open(">", "$file.$$");
```

The main idea would be to request for an admin to check the `git-daemon-export-ok.19906` permission and see if anything is amiss there.
The other idea would be to consider upgrading to the latest Gitolite v3 (v3.6.11, January 2019), using SSH only (no more git daemon).